# What is the true pronunciation of "participle"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, participles

I cannot seem to find anything on this. I see (in dictionaries, although not all of them) that the first syllable is stressed (I've been corrected countless number of times on this, too).

That means that many believe that saying it with stress on the second syllable is a way to broadcast that "you're an uneducated dummy who doesn't know how to pronounce it." But why? I don't understand.

The word "participate," for example, is on the second syllable, and it appears to me that the words are related etymologically (somehow...).

According to: https://www.etymonline.com/word/participle

> participle in the grammatical sense (13c.), a variant of participe,
>   and directly from Latin participium, literally "a sharing, partaking,"

This means that participe and participium are BOTH first-syllable pronunciations? That doesn't make sense.

Can someone explain? Or find some information that the second syllable is **truly** the wrong way to pronounce it?

Comment: There is no rule in English that related words have to be accented on the same syllable. Consider *relation* and *relative*. In Latin, the accent was usually on the third-to-last syllable, so it would have been [*parti**ci**pium.*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/participium#Latin) And *participe* was French, not Latin.

Comment: You need to add (and possibly reexamine) references. M-W gives different possible pronunciations; [Collins CoBuild] gives (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/participle) only pɑːʳtɪsɪpəl (which is the one I know, [I'm in the UK]). Anyone insisting one of the suggested variants is wrong is wrong.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -- I need to reexamine references? What else is there to reexamine? I'm confused exactly about that. Very little information exists on this word that I can find easily. Different dictionaries give different pronunciation variants, but people tend to stick to only one variant (first syllable). The question is *why* ... where is the linguistic rule to support the first syllable and not the second? And Peter, I know it's French. If you look at the link, you'll find that it actually does mention that.

Comment: 'I cannot seem to find anything on this.' But in the above comment, M-W licenses various different pronunciations, while Collins gives only the one with the stress on the second syllable, which means that its corpus data is heavily slanted towards this variant, and is probably UK-based. How can you still be unconvinced? There isn't a **single** 'true' pronunciation.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth -- so you're telling me that both are equally valid, disregarding the fact that real-life humans insist on there being only one pronunciation? How did this duality happen? Maybe I should start pronouncing "tomato" as "tomahto?"

I get your point, but you've not presented a reason **why** this is the case. Where did two pronunciations come from? Next, I'll be told that "aint" is pronounced as "ah-int" instead of "eh-int"... or that "persevere" is actually pronounced as "pErsevere" to sound more like "pers-veer"

Comment: Now you've changed your question from "What is the true pronunciation of X?" (The only possible reading of 'true' must be 'correct' here, and dictionaries give proper answers for today's correct pronunciations. For 'tomato', there are two pronunciations given at the [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/tomato) entry, both rather nice, neither wrong. If one group says one pronunciation is incorrect, they're wrong.) // Now you're asking "How have two equally valid pronunciations, one mainly used in the US and the other in the UK, arisen?" A far harder question.

Comment: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/participle) also gives two separate pronunciations for 'participle'; it marks one as 'US' and the other 'UK' (though doubtless there are adherents to the 'wrong camp' in both nations. Again, calling such people 'wrong' is incorrect, arguably racist.)

Comment: The “true pronunciation” of any English word is obviously the way I pronounce it. It may or may not be what is given in online dictionaries. Why not try one?

Comment: Both the Latin *participium* and the French *participe* have stress on the *cip* syllable. Does that mean that this is the "true" pronunciation? Absolutely not ... nobody uses it,  and thus it is indubitably wrong. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Peter Shaw Oh no. I prefer that pronunciation. It'll probably stick with me.

Comment: Oh, those crazy Brits! Here I was all prepared to give @LucidityofPower the side-eye, but then I looked it up: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/participle

Comment: @shoover Comment (2) above has already quoted (,attributed, and linked to) this.

Comment: Your example "participate" is *definitely* related to "participation', yet the two have emphasis on different syllables, so why should more distantly related words have emphasis on the same syllable?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Somehow I missed that on first reading while attempting to get through the wall o' comments. I think OP should pronounce the word as it is generally pronounced in OP's country. If OP lives in the US and pronounces it the UK way, they are going to get snickered at for sure.

Comment: **multiple, fungible, incorrigible, collectible**: for example. The stress is on the root or second part of the root for the second two. Also, un participe in French as a noun has the tonic accent (stress) on the last syllable like all words in French with more than one syllable (except for a few foreign borrowings). As for Latin, what has Latin got to do with it? Anyway, I doubt Brits would say: fungible with the stress on the second syllable. So why would participle be any different?

Comment: BBC English: participle https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8E5EF0IEN0 American English;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rff7AHbrx4E ***Both put the primary stress on the ti***. As in mu**ni**cipal. Of course, both these speakers are in the know. [ha ha]

Comment: @Lambie - How ’bout ***municipal***?

Comment: @Jim What's your point? Mine is that municipal and participle have the same stresses.

Comment: @Lambie - Hmmm,  No my point was that they have *different* stresses.  mew-NIH-sih-pul.  But PAR-tih-Sip-pul.  Not par-TIH-sih-pul.

Comment: @Lambie Before this evening, I had never heard anyone stress the second syllable of "participle" in 44 years of living in the US and 6 years living in Europe.

Comment: What is a "true" pronunciation? True to what?

Comment: @tchrist -- the pronunciation of certain words like Worcester are not "war-chester" or words like "colonel" are "kernel", not "kuh-luh-nell." There's a linguistic reason why and how it is pronounced. Most of the pronunciations are set in stone because of some sort of history and linking to an "ancestral analogue" in Latin, for example. That's what I was hoping to get for "participle."

Comment: @Jim Your point is sound. To be fair, in a strong collocation like 'municipal borough', I don't think I'd use a primary stress (other than on the first syllable of the noun in this case). But with say 'a new very municipal variety of dwarf sweet pea'
— Osbert Sitwell [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/municipal)], the stress would be on the second syllable.  [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/municipal) has the 'US pronunciation' with far more stress on the second syllable than the 'UK' pronunciation it offers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J. C. Wells, the phonetician, in his Pronunciation Dictionary (Longman, 3rd edition 2008) gives three possibilities for British English.

- ˈpɑ:t ɪs ɪp l, the most common pronunciation (spaces make the syllabification of the word clear)
- ˈpɑ:ts ɪp l, less common with only three syllables
- pɑ: ˈtɪs ɪp l, also less common than the first one with the stress on the second syllable

All three variants are considered acceptable.

When it comes to American English, only one possibility is given.

- ˈpɑ:rt̬ ə sɪp l

Presumably, in American English, stressing *participle* on the second syllable might be considered "wrong", while it wouldn't be the case in British English.

As to why, I'm not sure there is an answer.  Pronunciation can change over time, different ways of pronouncing a word can exist at the same time, one can replace the other.  Prague, for example, was recorded as only /preig/ by Michaelis and Jones in their Phonetic Dictionary of the English Language in 1913.  There must have been a time when /prɑ:g/ started being used as well as /preig/.  /preig/ has now completely died out for the Czech capital (I can't vouch for the way the various Pragues that exist in the U.S. are said though).  Why is anybody's guess.

Comment: I guess this is the best explanation so far. Thanks, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is "participle" pronounced with stress on the first syllable or the second syllable?

From Wiktionary:

> ## [participle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/participle)
>
> #### Pronunciation
>
> - (*Received Pronunciation*) [IPA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:International_Phonetic_Alphabet): /pɑːˈtɪsɪpəl/
> - (*US*) [IPA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:International_Phonetic_Alphabet): /ˈpɑɹtɪˌsɪpəl/

So *some* people stress the first syllable and *some* people stress the second syllable. According to Wiktionary, people in the US are more likely to stress the first syllable and people from the UK (*Received Pronunciation*) are more likely to stress the second syllable.

In each environment, the other pronunciation might be viewed as wrong.

The reason I like giving Wiktionary as a reference is that it refers to regional differences. The same entry from Oxford Learner's Dictionaries:

> ## [participle](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/participle) noun
>
> - /pɑːˈtɪsɪpl/
> - /ˈpɑːrtɪsɪpl/

Again both pronunciations are given, but no regional information.

English doesn't follow the pronunciation of other languages (e.g. Latin in your example). It only follows its own pronunciation, which almost inevitably varies by location.